# How does vibration transmitted through a horizontal surface cause the uniform rotary motion of objects sitting on the surface?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

On top of my washing machine is an aluminium tray, which holds various objects (used in the making of hot drinks). When the machine is on the final spin phase of its programme, it vibrates strongly. Then, all the objects on the tray steadily rotate in the same direction.

The objects also glide across the surface of the tray, and are easily steered with the gentlest nudge to any part of the tray, where they continue to rotate in the same direction.

I am familiar with how a mat laid on a carpet with a directional nap will tend to migrate in one direction. Arguably, the finishing of a metallic surface could similarly impart a ratchet-like directionality to its microstructure, so that the coefficient of friction varies slightly with the direction. However, I can't see how this could have a rotary analogue where the direction of rotation is constant, independent of the linear displacement.

What dynamics underlie this rotary behaviour and, in particular, why is the rotation uniformly in one direction rather than the other?

Additional information: the drum of the washing machine and the integral motor that drives it rotate about a horizontal axis.

Comment: Could you post a video, that would be helpful.

Comment: For a spin cycle, it seems likely that the vibration is a small rapid circular motion of the washing machine, possibly combined with bouncing up and down. It wouldn't be too surprizing if that induced rotation of objects sitting on it.

Comment: I would suggest attaching a level to the washing machine during the spin cycle. I believe @mmesser314 is correct. An unbalanced load will cause one end the washing machine to be slightly higher and the rotation gives a tilt towards the center that rotates. Similar to a constant radial force.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the slight off-balance of the motor induces a circular wave on
the top surface?   Otherwise, it could just be vibration causing
an interaction with asymmetry of the objects in motion.

Like your left and right hands have a difference, some shaped implements on your washing machine have chiral asymmetry. The perfectly symmetric spoon won't rotate, but the twisted one will, given any excitement by acoustic energy, and the direction of rotation depends on its shape.

There are toy 'celt stones' that demonstrate this effect [Celt stone](https://youtu.be/gCxEU26EQ5A?si=D2muMkxbd_i29PJr).

Comment: I can't find any reference to “circular wave” on the internet—except in the sense of a wave with circular symmetry radiating from a point. Nor can I find any mechanical “rotating waves”. (There is a rotating-wave approximation in the analysis of EM field equations, which seems quite irrelevant here.) Could you give me a pointer, please?  There are seven objects, of diverse age, material, and manufacture, with flat bottoms of different smoothness, all of which rotate in the same direction regardless of position. None of them looks anything like a Celt stone.

Comment: @JohnBentin A slight flexibility in the appliance could allow the top surface to tilt, and that tilt might progress in circular fashion.   That would make the friction forces on the surface interact with any capacity of an object to rotate.  If there's any 'bounce' of the object, it is also capable of being frictionless and very sensitive to small surface flexure.